# Track the number of users using the custom java function in an enterprise

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging, logstash, newrelic

We have developed a common functions packaged as a jar and available at the Nexus .

Different teams are downloading our jar and using our common functions in their project .

**Requirement is**
We want to know who many users/projects are calling our common functions.
Note - not exposed as APIs, exposed as jar
Any way to achieve this.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You would have to have a built-in talking-home functionality which logs the function calls inside your jar and sends them to you. Note, that you then still can't know about offline usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are logs generated.

You could use Logstash to consume your logs and push into Elastic Search.

> Logstash dynamically ingests, transforms, and ships your data
> regardless of format or complexity. Derive structure from unstructured
> data with grok, decipher geo coordinates from IP addresses, anonymize
> or exclude sensitive fields, and ease overall processing.

https://www.elastic.co/logstash

From Elastic Search, you have a lot of flexibility in how you aggregate data to figure our how many are using your function

https://www.elastic.co/

You can look into Kibana for visual representation of such data as well.

====== Edited ==========
In its simplest form, you will be able to find out:

- Project A is calling functionA()
- Project B is calling functionA(), and functionB()

You will not be able to tell which *User*, unless you are logging such information.

This all depends on what you are logging, what logstash is going to be parsing and pushing into Elastic Search.